# How to test bootstrap methods in node?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I have a react component that has the following line in componentDidMount():

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

When I run my test, I get:

> TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

I have global.$ defined, but I wonder if there is a way to stub out the tooltip() function when my tests are run.  I don't care if the tooltip() is stubbed, I just need my test to run.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ask global.$ to return object with a .tooltip function

```
global.$ = function () { 
    return {
        tooltip: function() { console.log(42) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mindless, that's perfect!  Out of curiousity, is 42 a special number? :)

Comment: @MarkKadlec - "The number 42 is, in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy by Douglas Adams, the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything", calculated by an enormous supercomputer named Deep Thought over a period of 7.5 million years. Unfortunately, no one knows what the question is."